# Richard's Favourite TV Programme

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

My friend Richard is a huge TV fan so I recently asked him for some recommendations.

He wouldn't tell me his favourite show but sent me a list of descriptions of some shows he likes to watch:

> - Drama, set in the sixties, focusing on the executive of a company which produces alcoholic drinks from fermented honey.
> - Two wealthy socialites visit a farm to investigate triangles and their generalisations.
> - Documentary presenting a unique look at the pills consumed in the world's most renowned kitchens.
> - A highschool mathlete and her younger brother start hanging out with a group of Mediterraneans.
> - Thriller about two FBI agents tasked with interviewing people with ghosts in their heads.
> - Police investigating corruption tackle one of the most frustrating aspects of sweeping dirt off the floor.

Unfortunately, I could not find any of these TV programmes to watch.
I think my friend is playing a joke on me.

**Can you tell me Richard's favourite programme?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think Richard's favourite programme is

> EXTRAS, which is apparently the name of a BBC sitcom from a few years back.

The shows he listed are:

Drama, set in the sixties, focusing on the executive of a company which produces alcoholic drinks from fermented honey.

> M**E**AD MEN

Two wealthy socialites visit a farm to investigate triangles and their generalisations.

> THE SIMPLE**X** LIFE

Documentary presenting a unique look at the pills consumed in the world's most renowned kitchens.

> CHEF'S TABLE**T**

A highschool mathlete and her younger brother start hanging out with a group of Mediterraneans.

> FREAKS AND G**R**EEKS

Thriller about two FBI agents tasked with interviewing people with ghosts in their heads.

> MINDH**A**UNTERS (thanks to @cinico for pointing this one out to me in comments!)

Police investigating corruption tackle one of the most frustrating aspects of sweeping dirt off the floor.

> LINE OF DU**S**T(y)

and so

> the letters we have had to add to get his fanciful new programmes are E, X, T, R, A, S.

Credit where due:

> I found all of the above *except* MINDHUNTERS, kindly pointed out in comments by user @cinico. (And also, slightly later, by @Quantoss.) Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard about a TV show called mindhunter? :)

Comment: Well, I have _now_. I hadn't before reading your comment. (I don't know a damn thing about TV, actually; of the shows used here I'd heard of exactly two before.) Thanks!

Comment: The FBI thirller could be rot13(ZVAQU(N)HAGREF)
Edit: Damn you @cinico, beat me by minute :D

Comment: Of the shows used here I'd heard of exactly *none* before. The rock I live under must be bigger than yours :-P

Comment: Good work, the title of the second last is just singular, by the way. And to you and @Randal'Thor I would certainly recommend the last two if you have any inclination to watching TV at all.